# Vaadin 17 Grid change style of the second header row

Tags: grid, vaadin-flow

Is there a way to change the style (color, font) of the second header row added to Vaadin 17 grid?
Second header row is added with grid.appendHeaderRow();

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever component you like to the Header Row.

For example:

```
Div div = new Div();
// add classes or styles to the Div

HeaderRow headerRow = employeeGrid.appendHeaderRow();
headerRow.getCell(idColumn).setComponent();
```

Checkout the examples here:

https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/header-and-footer